# jQuery target elements with corresponding id number

Tags: jquery

Here is my  code

```
if(jQuery.cookie("box1") == "close") {
        jQuery("#box1").remove();
};
```

I already have individual cookies for each box. Now i want to check the cookies with jquery and remove the corresponding box if the cookie value is 'close'.

How can i make that code work with other boxes? .Other boxes have similar IDs (box2, box3) and there's a cookie for each one

Comment: i don't know how to get it working with other boxes. I don't want to simple repeat that code for each box

Comment: What will you be storing in the cookie that would store the names? Can you post an example?

Comment: when the close button is pressed, the box is removed and a cookie is stored.
Cookie name = boxID value=yes
Where ID is a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think the cookie plugin has an option to iterate over cookies, but you could get all the set cookies yourself and just iterate over them to see if the value is `close`, and then remove the corresponding element, something like :

```
function get_cookies() {
    var cookies = { };
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var split = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            var name_value = split[i].split("=");
            name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
            cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
        }
    }
    return cookies;
}

var cookies = get_cookies();
for(var name in cookies) {
    if (cookies[name] == 'close') jQuery("#"+name).remove();
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this `jquery.cookie` plugin: [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md).

It will allow you to get the required results using code similar to this:

```
if ($.cookie('box1') === 'close') {
    $('#box').remove();
}
```

Alternatively what you could do, whilst still using this plugin, is have a JSON object stored in your cookie of boxes to hide, that way you could make it slightly more generic, and implement it with the following:

```
// assuming the cookie: boxes-to-hide is an array of string id ['box1', 'box2']
$($.cookie('boxes-to-hide')).each(function() {
    // this will be the id of the box to hide
    $('#' + this).remove();
});
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but looking at his syntax I'd suggest that he might already be using the jQuery.cookie plugin, possibly in no-conflict, but the syntax looks identical.